# Cloudkit fetch data (strings and image asset) take a long time to appear after call

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cloudkit

I was hoping that someone can help a coding newbie with what might be considered a stupid question. I'm making a blog type app for a community organization and it's pretty basic. It'll have tabs where each tab may be weekly updates, a table view with past updates and a tab with general information.

I setup cloudkit to store strings and pictures, and then created a fetchData method to query cloud kit. In terms of the code (sample below) it works and gets the data/picture. My problem is that it takes almost 5-10 seconds before the text and image update when I run the app. I'm wondering if that's normal, and I should just add an activity overlay for 10 seconds, or is there a way to decrease the time it takes to update.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    fetchUpcoming()
}

func fetchUpcoming() {
    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicData = container.publicCloudDatabase

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Upcoming", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
        if error == nil { // There is no error

            println(results)
            for entry in results {
                self.articleTitle.text = entry["Title"] as? String
                self.articleBody.text = entry["Description"] as? String
                let imageAsset: CKAsset = entry["CoverPhoto"] as! CKAsset
                self.articlePicture.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageAsset.fileURL.path!)
                self.articleBody.sizeToFit()
                self.articleBody.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified
                self.articleTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true    

            }
        }
        else {
            println(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Another question I had is about string content being stored on cloud kit. If I want to add multiple paragraphs to a blood entry (for example), is there a way to put it in one record, or do I have to separate the blog entry content into separate paragraphs? I may be mistaken but it seems like CloudKit records don't recognize line breaks. If you can help answer my questions, I'd be really appreciative.

Comment: is the network connection slow? or the rendering of the view? if the rendering is slow, after the service fetches your data try updating your views on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be issuing a query after creating the data, which isn't necessary. When you save data, as soon as your completion block succeeds (with no errors) then you can be sure the data is stored on the server and you can go ahead and render it to the user.

For example, let's say you're using a [CKModifyRecordsOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKModifyRecordsOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKModifyRecordsOperation) to save the data and you assign a block of code to the [modifyRecordsCompletionBlock](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKModifyRecordsOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CKModifyRecordsOperation/modifyRecordsCompletionBlock) property. As soon as that block runs and no errors are passed in, then you can render your data and images to your user. You have the data (strings, images, etc.) locally because you just sent them to the server, so there's no need to go request them again.

**This provides a quicker experience for the user and reduces the amount of network requests and battery you're using on their device.**

If you are just issuing normal queries when your app boots up, then that amount of time does seem long but there can be a lot of factors: your local network, the size of the image you're downloading, etc. so it's hard to say without more information.

Regarding the storage of paragraphs of text, you should consider using a CKAsset. Here is a quote from the CKRecord's documentation about string data:

> Use strings to store relatively small amounts of text. Although
>   strings themselves can be any length, you should use an asset to store
>   large amounts of text.

You'll need to make sure you're properly storing and rendering line break characters between the user input and what you send to CloudKit.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm actually trying to use cloudkit as a backend so that in can add new content (eg upcoming events) on the cloudkit dashboard. Then when the user opens the app, they'll query for any updated information.